# Change localtime in SuSE

Tags: sles

I changed this file and rebooted the server:

```
myserver: # cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
TIMEZONE="Europe/Berlin"
DEFAULT_TIMEZONE="Europe/Berlin"
SYSTOHC="yes"
```

Unfortunately the output of `date` is still using the old value (US/Pacific).

```
myserver: # date
Fr 31. Aug 04:34:21 PDT 2018
```

How to update localtime on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
yast2 timezone
```

If you want to do it manually, change the symlink `/etc/localtime` to

```
/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin
```